# Flutter: How to fix and add a border and color to outlined button?

Tags: flutter, colors, flutter2.0, border-radius

Can someone tell me why my code is not making the border blue, and let it have width of 3.0?

This is what it looks like (L: my app, R: tutorial app):
[image]

The code:

```
class CreateRoomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () => print('Create Room'),
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
              width: 3.0,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (rect) =>
                Palette.createRoomGradient.createShader(rect),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.video_call,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 35.0,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 4.0),
          Text(
            'Create\nRoom',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent[100]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also I have to add this somewhere (but since textColor is depreciated in flutter 2.0, idk what to do with it...):

```
textColor: Palette.facebookblue,
```

thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change your OutlinedButton to this:

```
OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () => print('Create Room'),
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      ),
      side: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.blueAccent[100]),
    )
    child: yourChildWidget,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this and in child you can write your widget

```dart
OutlinedButton(
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: null,
),
```